# Issue with app auto-update on multiple android devices with same google account

Tags: android

I am facing a weird issue. I have installed my app on multiple android devices with same google account on all devices. Whenever i published update for my app it does not auto-update on all devices, I have to manually update it on some of the devices. Is there some issue with Play-store app on these devices? or am i doing some thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store app generally updates apps when the device is charging and connected to wifi to save power. Perhaps that's why you are seeing that behavior.